# how can I list all static builtin drivers in kernel, such as pcieport and pciehp?

Tags: kernel, drivers, pci-express, kernel-modules

with lspci I can see things like:

```
Slot:   00:02.0
Class:  PCI bridge [0604]
Vendor: Red Hat, Inc. [1b36]
Device: QEMU PCIe Root port [000c]
Driver: pcieport
```

In dmesg I can see `pcieport 0000:00:02.0: pciehp: Slot #0 AttnBtn+ PwrCtrl+ MRL- AttnInd+ PwrInd+ HotPlug+ Surprise+ Interlock+ NoCompl- IbPresDis- LLActRep+`

However, `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin | grep pci` does not show any of them. `depmod -v` neither.

So I guess, these 2 drivers are actually static builtin in the kernel which is not module. In kernel config (`/boot/config-$(uname -r)`) I can see `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_PCIE=y`. But I do not even know this flag till I dig into the kernel source code. I wonder is there any easy way to list all the driver names of static builtins?

Comment: Probably they are not compiled as module.

Comment: can be static builtin in the kernel. But how do I list those static ones? I want to see all drivers available

Comment: What exactly do you mean by list / see though? The build config of the kernel you are using? Or are you looking for the location of corresponding source code in the tree?

Comment: I want the static driver names according to current system's kernel config. I know the kernel config in /boot, but that is not straightforward. I try to get the actual driver names as in `/sys/bus/pci_express/drivers` not something like `CONFIG_X86_TSC=y` from the current kernel config, it is hard to associate it with the actual driver names.